# Adding objects to queue without interruption

Tags: python, queue, locking, atomic

I would like to put two objects into a queue, but I've got to be sure the objects are in both queues at the same time, therefore it should not be interrupted in between - something like an atomic block. Does some one have a solution? Many thanks...

```
queue_01.put(car)
queue_02.put(bike)
```

Comment: The title and content of your question are contradictory. Please be consistent. Are you wanting to put two objects in one queue, or two objects in two queues. Why do you care about the atomic? Are you running multi-threaded code?

Comment: Sorry, the title is misleading. I want to write a object into one queue and another object into another queue (see code). And its multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Condition object](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects). You can tell the threads to wait with `cond.wait()`, and signal when the queues are ready with `cond.notify_all()`. See, for example, Doug Hellman's wonderful [Python Module of the Week blog](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html#synchronizing-threads-with-a-condition-object). His code uses `multiprocessing`; here I've adapted it for `threading`:

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

def stage_1(cond,q1,q2):
    """perform first stage of work, then notify stage_2 to continue"""
    with cond:
        q1.put('car')
        q2.put('bike')
        print 'stage_1 done and ready for stage 2'
        cond.notify_all()
def stage_2(cond,q):
    """wait for the condition telling us stage_1 is done"""
    name=threading.current_thread().name
    print 'Starting', name
    with cond:
        cond.wait()
        print '%s running' % name
def run():
    # http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html#synchronizing-threads-with-a-condition-object
    condition=threading.Condition()
    queue_01=Queue.Queue()
    queue_02=Queue.Queue()    
    s1=threading.Thread(name='s1', target=stage_1, args=(condition,queue_01,queue_02))
    s2_clients=[
        threading.Thread(name='stage_2[1]', target=stage_2, args=(condition,queue_01)),
        threading.Thread(name='stage_2[2]', target=stage_2, args=(condition,queue_02)),
        ]
    # Notice stage2 processes are started before stage1 process, and yet they wait
    # until stage1 finishes
    for c in s2_clients:
        c.start()
        time.sleep(1)
    s1.start()
    s1.join()
    for c in s2_clients:
        c.join()

run()
```

Running the script yields

```
Starting stage_2[1]
Starting stage_2[2]
stage_1 done and ready for stage 2  <-- Notice that stage2 is prevented from running until the queues have been packed.
stage_2[2] running
stage_2[1] running
```

Answer (score 0):

To atomically add to two different queues, acquire the locks for both queues first.  That's easiest to do by making a subclass of Queue that uses recursive locks.

```
import Queue # Note: module renamed to "queue" in Python 3
import threading

class MyQueue(Queue.Queue):
    "Make a queue that uses a recursive lock instead of a regular lock"
    def __init__(self):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self)
        self.mutex = threading.RLock()

queue_01 = MyQueue()
queue_02 = MyQueue()

with queue_01.mutex:
    with queue_02.mutex:
        queue_01.put(1)
        queue_02.put(2)
```